# No module named 'mysql' in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

I am getting this error in my Jupiter notebook. I don't get this error when I test it in my cmd with activated AHG_web kernel. I use the same kernel in my Jupiter notebook.

you may see the attached picture for more info.
[image]

how can I solve the issue.

Comment: The notebook and the terminal are using different interpreters. This can be confirmed by executing `import sys ; print(sys.executable)` in both and comparing the output

Comment: you are right, although I select the same kernel in my notebook but still it uses different kernel

Comment: @DeepSpace, I select the same kernel from my notebook when I want to execute it. but still, it behaves differently. do you know how can I solve it?